# Custom keyboard shortcut not working, am I doing this right? Ctrl+Alt+R does nothing

Tags: shortcut-keys, 13.10, customization

In this image i have what I've setup for a custom keyboard shortcut to start `tmux` but it's not working. Is it `tmux`? Or something else?

[image]

I've logged in and out.

Comment: Same problem, I want to add `mpc prev`, `mpc next` and `mpc toggle`. I'm running mpd to listen to local music on my HDD. Also trying to add them I changed something and now my volume control keys also don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just put`gnome-terminal -x <command>` in the command section; which works fine, but leaves a useless terminal window open. I haven't figured out how to hide that yet.